# Understanding an RLE coverage value

Tags: r, range, bioconductor

Using R and bioconductor.

I'm not sure how to  understand an integer rle that you'd get from functions like coverage() such as this

```
integer-Rle of length 3312 with 246 runs
  Lengths:  25  34 249  16   7  11  16 ...   2  32   2  26  34  49
  Values :   0   1   0   1   2   3   2 ...   1   2   1   0   1   0
```

Okay so I get that it represents coverage of one range vs other ranges. In this case reads of an experiment over a given range. What do the 'runs' mean? What about the 'Lengths' and 'Values'? I thought that maybe Lengths represent a postion and values represent the amount of times its covered but then why would there be multiples of the same position such as 2 above? Why would they be out of order?

I ask because I'm using

```
sum(coverage)
```

to compare the coverage of one range to another of a different length and I was wondering if that was appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it's better to ask about Bioconductor packages on the Bioconductor [support site](https://support.bioconductor.org).

The interpretation is that there is a run of 25 nucleotides with 0 coverage, then a run of 24 nucleotides with 1 coverage (i.e., a single read) then another run of 249 nucleotides with no coverage, then things start to get interesting as multiple reads overlap positions. From the summary line at the top of the output, your read covers 3312 nucleotides, maybe from a single transcript? If you were to

```
plot(as.integer(coverage))
```

you'd get a quick plot of how coverage varies along the length of the transcript.

Maybe `sum(coverage)` is appropriate; a more usual metric is to count reads rather than coverage, e.g., with `GenomicRanges::summarizeOverlaps()` illustrated in this [DESeq2 work flow](http://bioconductor.org/help/workflows/rnaseqGene/#count) in the context of RNA-seq.

Comment: okay so the lengths are consecutive right? ie the first 25 nucleotides have zero reads then the next 34 have a read etc?

Answer (score 0):

This might help to understand the concept of RLE: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypdNscvym_E

Here is an easy example:

```
> x <- IRanges(start=c(-2L, 1L, 3L),
+              width=c( 5L, 4L, 6L))
> x
IRanges of length 3
    start end width
[1]    -2   2     5
[2]     1   4     4
[3]     3   8     6
> coverage(x)
integer-Rle of length 8 with 2 runs
  Lengths: 4 4
  Values : 2 1
```

The output means the first 4 places are in packs of 2 and the next four places are in single-packs. All places including 0 and below 0 were ignored!
The length means that the complete range that we are looking at, so to say all places together, are 8. 
The runs are the types of packs that occur. Here, we only have overlaps that include two ranges (pack of two) and overlaps that don't really overlap (single pack).